# ParsIng BIng Image Search using JQuery or Javascript Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, bing

I can successfully parse Bing Search JSON API correctly. Using Version 7 of both Web Search and Images. For some reason JSONLint is correct for images but but can not parse a damn thing. My JQuery code is below Thanks in advance!

```
 ////JQUERY CODE
  $(document).on("click", "#i-search", function () { 

 //API URL
 var uri  = 'bing-img.php';

//SEARCH PARAMETERS
var e = escape($('#book').val());
var pg = escape($('#pg').val());;
var limit = escape($('#limit').val());;
var market = "en-us";


  $.ajax({

  url: uri,
  method: "GET",
  data: { q:e, s:limit, p:pg, m:market },
  success: function(data) {

  var obj = JSON.parse(data)

  //SEARCH RESULTS
  var ocean = obj.value; //client prop is an array

  for(var i = 0; i < ocean.length; i++){
 
 //alert(ocean[i].thumbnail);

 var ocean_format = '<p><a href="' + ocean[i].thumbnailUrl + '" class="cLink"'  + ocean[i].name + '">' + ocean[i].name +'</a></p>';

 $("#bookout").append(ocean_format);

        }//END SEARCH RESULTS


    $("#moreout").html(more);

    },

    error: function() {
   // console.log(data);
  }
});

}); //END IMAGE SEARCH SUBMIT
```

/////// VALID BING IMAGE JSON ////////////
https://0ct0p.us/bing-img.php?q=mazda&s=2&p=0&m=en-us

/////CROSS ORGIN ERROR ON FIREFOX
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Comment: Can you provide a complete snippet?  If the issue is with the result and not the ajax request, then maybe include a result (in a fiddle if too long for here).  Your url is CORS blocked:  https://jsfiddle.net/dwez894x/

Comment: I [had another go](https://jsfiddle.net/dwez894x/1/) - you have `obj.value.thumbnail` but `obj.value` is an array so doesn't have a `thumbnail` property.  With that changed to just `obj.value`, your code [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/dwez894x/2/)  Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I have very similar code for bing web search and has been working for months, the bing images is the one giving me issues... pain in the arse... using firefox web dev tools and get proper JSON responses, just the JQuery giving me issues... Thanks!

Comment: If you read down your code, then you have: get value thumbnail, loop through this and get thumbnails.   So your json would need to be:  `data.value.thumbnail[].thumbnail` - which it's not, it's `data.value.thumbnail[]`